# What does the searchbar in SourceTree do?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, searchbar

I'm using SourceTTree 1.9.10.0 under Win10. I can't figure out, what this little searchbar is for. It doesn't seem to do anything. I'm typing, waiting, pushing enter, but it has no effect.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It will search the files in your repository. From your screenshot, if you searched for ReleaseNotes it would find the file.

Comment: I've just checked and it doesn't seem to work. Could it just be broken?

Comment: possibly, I'm using version 1.9.10.0